# The argument 'sql' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space. When first create the database

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm using `entity framework` to process the `sqlite` database. If there's no database and I want to insert one record, it will create the database successfully (I found the database file in disk) but throw the error:

> The argument 'sql' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.".

Then next time running, because the database has been created, all code works well with no error.

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCmd, parameters.ToArray());
```

Only throw above error when `Database` not exist. If exist, work well.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur in case the "sqlCmd" variable is null or empty when the ExecuteSqlCommand method is called. Please make sure that this variable is correctly initialized in case the database does not exist.

Comment: The "sqlCmd" does have value. I can find it through debug. Obviously entityframework does some other "process" when the database does not exist.